# Understanding Galois groups, too simple argumentation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I am currently studying Galois Theory, and there I read the paper

[Analyzing the Galois Groups of Fifth-Degree and Fourth-Degree Polynomials](http://vc.bridgew.edu/undergrad_rev/vol7/iss1/7/)

In it the author states (page 26, case 1)

"Let's look at $f(x) = x - 1$ and $f(x) = x^2 + 3x + 2$. Both have coefficients and solutions that lie in $\mathbb Q$. When these conditions are met the only possible permutation on the rational numbers is the identity. Therefore, the Galois group for these types of polynomials is the trivial group $S_1$."

What does he mean "by these conditions met", this case gives no insight to me. The function $f$ has two root $-2$ and $-1$, so why I just can apply the identity permutation on them and not exchange them, like I do when I have a polynomial which has an imaginary root?

Comment: The elements of the Galois group have to fix the underlying field, which in this case is $\mathbb{Q}$. But actually this restriction is automatic: if $K$ is any field of characteristic zero, then any automorphism of it whatsoever fixes $\mathbb{Q} \subset K$ (exercise).

Comment: Your link doesn't work for me.

Comment: oh sorry, I used google, but I don't know how to get at the link... just google the title and the first hit is the paper.

Comment: "When these conditions are met" means, "when a polynomial only has rational roots."

Comment: @Stefan: the definition given for Galois group in the paper is incomplete. It is not arbitrary permutations of the roots, but only those that can be extended additively and multiplicatively to all (additive and multiplicative = polynomial) expressions in those roots.

Comment: The quoted passage looks regrettably poorly written. One might hope that this is not your only source for Galois Theory.

Comment: @Stefan: so if we decide to switch -2 and -1, then we send -1 to -2, and so -1 + -1 to -2 + -2. But wait, -1 + -1 = -2, and we wanted to send it to -1, not to -4. Oops.

Comment: Ok, think I got it :) No, it's not my only source. Btw how did you extracted the link from these wild links google gives you?

Comment: @stefan: I just searched that university's library for the paper by title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Galois Group is given by the set of $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphisms of the splitting field $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(\operatorname{f})$.

A $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphism is an automorphism that fixes $\mathbb{Q}$. (It is a map from the field to itself, which is an additive and multiplicative homomorphism.)

In the example you give, since the roots of $x^2+3x+2$ are already rational, we don't need to extend $\mathbb{Q}$ to be able to factorise $x^2+3x+2$. So the splitting field $\mathbb{Q}/(x^2+3x+2)$ is just $\mathbb{Q}$. Clearly, the only automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}$ that fixes $\mathbb{Q}$ is the identity. So the Galois Group is trivial.

What the author means is that any polynomial with rational coefficients, i.e. in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, that factories over $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e. has $\mathbb{Q}$ as its splitting field, will have the trivial group as its Galois Group. The only automorphism from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ that fixes $\mathbb{Q}$ is the identity!

Comment: That's only the splitting field in this and other limited examples. It's misleading to give the impression that you don't, in general, have to repeat the construction of adjoining a root up to $n$ times.